# scss sass doesn't found in nuxt3 and Vite

Tags: nuxt3

I have a problem to get scss in my nuxt3 project.
In the documentation it sounds really simple but it does not work for me.

The path can be written with @ or tilde or nothing (I have seen various types) but the outcome is everytime the same.

```
500[vite-node] Failed to load /assets/styles/main.scss
at ViteNodeRunner.directRequest (./node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:215:13)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async ViteNodeRunner.cachedRequest (./node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:146:14)
at async request (./node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:172:16)
at async ./virtual/app/.nuxt/css.mjs:3:31
at async ViteNodeRunner.directRequest (./node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:285:5)
at async ViteNodeRunner.cachedRequest (./node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:146:14)
at async request (./node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:172:16)
at async ./node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/entry.mjs:9:31
at async ViteNodeRunner.directRequest (./node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:285:5)
```

my nuxt.config.ts file:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    pages: true,

    css: [
        'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass',
        'assets/styles/main.scss'
    ],
    build: {
        transpile: ['vuetify'],
        
    },
    runtimeConfig: {
        public: {
            baseURL: process.env.API_URL_BROWSER,
            baseSsrURL: process.env.API_URL
            // baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL || 'https://api.example.com/',
        },
    },
    vite: {
        define: {
            'process.env.DEBUG': false,
        },
    },
    modules: [
        '@pinia/nuxt',
        '@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt'
    ]
})​​​​
```

my Folderstructure:

project
-- nuxtjs
---- assets
------ styles
-------- main.scss

Can someone help me??

I tried different paths. No one works. @/assets/... ; ~/assets/... ; assets/...;
I was expecting, that one of it works but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm my application i'm use  `css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass', '@/assets/styles/main.scss'],`

the errors in Nuxt3 it's dificult to find and fix